# Trigger observer when new property added to Ember Object

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript

I want to fire an observer that will set a value to a property when another Ember Object has a new property set. So far this is how I've got it:

```
  relationTotalCountObserver: Ember.observer('item.relationships.attachments', ->
  totalCount = @get 'item.relationships.attachments.totalCount'
  if totalCount isnt undefined
    @set 'relationTotalCount', totalCount
  ).on 'init'
```

The item does not have any **totalCount** property before, it will be added eventually using a merge patch and I need to detect that addition somehow.

Comment: Why not oberserve for totalCount like  Ember.observer('item.relationships.attachments.totalCount'

Comment: When observer is installed on 'init' the item.relationships.attachments.totalCount property does not yet exist, it will added afterwards and apparently observer will never fire because it is not observing anything.

Comment: Will this work? I used notifyPropertyChange http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jeqaca/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: No, sorry. the observer is added to the 'item.relationships.attachments' property instead of the 'item.relationships.attachments.totalCount' one. The addition of the property does not seem to trigger the observer.

Comment: Ember.observer('item.relationships.attachments.totalCount') should just work. What version of Ember are you using?

Comment: 1.13.11 and unfortunately I cannot upgrade in a near future

Comment: Can you try to reproduce it in a JSBin? The one I made just seems to work: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zinizehayu/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Hello. Yes, I made it work finally, the origin of the problem was in another place. Thank you!

Comment: Hello. This is how it is more accurately my actual scenario. Still observer does not fire. http://emberjs.jsbin.com/fuzidamasi/edit?html,js,output